# Import graphml file in mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, import

I am trying import a graphml file I created with NodeXL in mathematica in order to create a network.

However when i try to import it I get the error message: "Cannot import data as GraphML format".

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!!

Comment: you will likely need to make an example file available

Comment: I have voted to close this question, as it lacks the minimum details necessary to answer it. There is a small chance [this other more detailed question and answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280433/10397)  is related to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded graph [57698](http://www.nodexlgraphgallery.org/Pages/GraphML.ashx?graphID=57698) from the NodeXL Graph Gallery, changed the suffix from "xml" to "graphml", tried to `Import`, and got the same error you report.

Now I don't know anything about XML, but I noticed that GraphML files generated by NetworkX have a namespace that NodeXL didn't include: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. Adding it made the import work ... no clue why.

My modified GraphML file begins with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but I cannot seem to make it work. This is what I get:     Information::notfound: Symbol xml not found. >>

Information::nomatch: No symbol matching version="1.0" found. >>

Information::nomatch: No symbol matching encoding="UTF-8"?> found. >>

Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as GraphML format. >>

Set::write: Tag Times in http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns (xmlns:xsi) is Protected. >>

Set::write: Tag Times in graphml xmlns is Protected. >>

Comment: Can't provide any further suggestions without a link to an example file that doesn't import. Please post an answer to your own question if resolved.