# How to import GraphML with a bad DTD URL?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

***Has the GraphML standard been updated?***

I downloaded the Rome database from the [link](http://www.graphdrawing.org/data.html).

[image]

The files in it are stored in the `"GraphML"` format. However, I am unable to import it into *Mathematica* or the YEd software. I would like to know what is happening and how to import them correctly. A similar unsolved issue can be found at the following link:

- [Import graphml file in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100324/import-graphml-file-in-mathematica)

```
Import["D:/grafo113.28.graphml"]
```

**Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as GraphML format.**

Example (grafo113.28.graphml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file was written by the internal XML-Handler of Y-Files.-->
<!DOCTYPE graphml SYSTEM "http://www.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd">
<graphml>
<graph edgedefault="undirected" id="G">
<node id="n0"/>
<node id="n1"/>
<node id="n2"/>
<node id="n3"/>
<node id="n4"/>
<node id="n5"/>
<node id="n6"/>
<node id="n7"/>
<node id="n8"/>
<node id="n9"/>
<node id="n10"/>
<node id="n11"/>
<node id="n12"/>
<node id="n13"/>
<node id="n14"/>
<node id="n15"/>
<node id="n16"/>
<node id="n17"/>
<node id="n18"/>
<node id="n19"/>
<node id="n20"/>
<node id="n21"/>
<node id="n22"/>
<node id="n23"/>
<node id="n24"/>
<node id="n25"/>
<node id="n26"/>
<node id="n27"/>
<edge id="e0" source="n1" target="n12"/>
<edge id="e1" source="n12" target="n2"/>
<edge id="e2" source="n12" target="n0"/>
<edge id="e3" source="n0" target="n14"/>
<edge id="e4" source="n14" target="n3"/>
<edge id="e5" source="n20" target="n8"/>
<edge id="e6" source="n3" target="n15"/>
<edge id="e7" source="n3" target="n16"/>
<edge id="e8" source="n16" target="n5"/>
<edge id="e9" source="n3" target="n17"/>
<edge id="e10" source="n3" target="n18"/>
<edge id="e11" source="n19" target="n7"/>
<edge id="e12" source="n7" target="n21"/>
<edge id="e13" source="n4" target="n15"/>
<edge id="e14" source="n21" target="n9"/>
<edge id="e15" source="n9" target="n13"/>
<edge id="e16" source="n9" target="n22"/>
<edge id="e17" source="n22" target="n11"/>
<edge id="e18" source="n23" target="n3"/>
<edge id="e19" source="n18" target="n7"/>
<edge id="e20" source="n18" target="n24"/>
<edge id="e21" source="n24" target="n6"/>
<edge id="e22" source="n25" target="n23"/>
<edge id="e23" source="n25" target="n24"/>
<edge id="e24" source="n25" target="n13"/>
<edge id="e25" source="n19" target="n16"/>
<edge id="e26" source="n25" target="n26"/>
<edge id="e27" source="n26" target="n10"/>
<edge id="e28" source="n27" target="n13"/>
<edge id="e29" source="n27" target="n8"/>
<edge id="e30" source="n7" target="n26"/>
</graph>
</graphml>
```

---

It looks like Syed is right. But I'm not sure what's behind the `Import` function. So now I don't understand why deleting that line `<!DOCTYPE graphml SYSTEM "http://www.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd">`  is OK.

Comment: This seems to be an older file. Remove the `<!DOCTYPE...` line and try again.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'm not sure why this line  ` <!DOCTYPE... ` leads to destruction. I don't know exactly how this function works, right.

Comment: It fails with `Import[..., "XML"]` as well, unless specifying `"ReadDTD" -> False`. But that option cannot be used with `Import[..., "GraphML"]`, so yes: find a way to remove that line. E.g., `ImportString[
 StringRiffle[
  Select[StringSplit[Import[file, "String"], "\n"], 
   Not@*StringStartsQ["<!DOCTYPE"]], "\n"],
 "GraphML"
 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Understanding the Problem

`"GraphML"` is an [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) format. All these files start with

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!-- This file was written by the internal XML-Handler of Y-Files.-->
> <!DOCTYPE graphml SYSTEM "http://www.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd">
> <graphml>
> ```

The `"!DOCTYPE"` declaration above contains a reference to a [*Document Type Definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) (DTD) file. The purpose of a DTD is to define the structure and the legal elements and attributes of an XML document. An XML document validated against a DTD is both "Well Formed" and "Valid".

The URL for the [*Document Type Definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) file `"http://www.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd"` is no longer valid, and needs to be replaced, or its reference deleted as mentioned by @Syed in the comments.

```
URLExecute["http://www.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd"]
(* Not Found  
The requested URL /dtds/graphml.dtd was not found on this server. *)
```

## Solutions

@Szabolcs showed already how to delete the invalid line.

Here I [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) one of the `"rome/grafo1049.21.graphml"` file as a `"String"`, [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) the invalid URL with a valid URL for the `"graphml.dtd"` file, and then [`ImportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html) in the `"GraphML"` format.

```
ImportString[
    StringReplace[
        Import[
            "http://www.graphdrawing.org/download/rome-graphml.tgz"
            , {"TAR", "rome/grafo1049.21.graphml", "String"}
        ]
    , "http://www.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd" -> "http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/dtds/1.0rc/graphml.dtd"
    ]
    ,"GraphML"
]
```

[image]

You can replace the URL `"http://www.graphdrawing.org/download/rome-graphml.tgz"` with the local path to your downloaded file.

## Comment

By the way, notice that you don't need to unpack your `"rome-graphml.tgz"` file to [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) the files inside. Here I don't even download the whole file.

You can first just get the file names and then Import only the one you need directly, as shown above.

```
fileNameList = Import[
  "http://www.graphdrawing.org/download/rome-graphml.tgz"
  , {"TAR", "FileNames"}
];
```